# How can i return 2 numbers with one decimal?

Tags: php, decimal, rounding, number-formatting

I return this number from my query: `44397.6345`

and I want to display it in this format: `44.4`

Comment: Divide it by a thousand and then use `round()`?

Comment: if only there was some kind of search engine....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
number_format(44397.6345 / 1000, 1)
```

(Note: based on your example, I'm assuming you also want to divide it by 1000)

Comment: I used number format but i didn't divide it by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$number = 1000;
echo  number_format((float)$number, 1, '.', '');// 1000.0
$number = 44397.6345;
echo  number_format((float)$number, 1, '.', '');// 44397.6
```

**NOTE: output as string.**